# Jquery - How i can save matrix in cookie

Tags: jquery

I have one matrix composed of one list of the DOM Object

I'm tryed this method:

```
 jQuery.cookie('matrizTela', vList, {expires: 7});

 var coo = jQuery.cookie('matrizTela');
 console.log(coo);
```

but return comming this:

```
,[object Object]
```

How i can save matrix in cookie and recovery this matrix without comma

Comment: Did you tried to serialize the date before save in the cookie?
$(vList).serializeArray()?
Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: cookies are better for eating than saving data, but make sure that you try to save a string rather than a array

Comment: @demonofnight my return is "[] "

Comment: It seems that you are saving the data in the wrong way. Serialize the data before u save it in the array